# Logic Apps - Get Email (V3) limit to 25 emails

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm fetching emails through Get Email (V3) and passing them into foreach loop.

But it only fetch top 25 emails and continue on.

How can I fetch all emails into foreach loop?

Thank you,

T.T

Answer (score -1):

It's actually not difficult.

I nested action Get Email (V3) into Until Loop so each iteration will fetch 25 emails until number of iteration = total amount of email / 25.

If anyone interest, I can post answer up